# Trusting the manufacturer like Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

I just purchased a Toshiba Excite 10.  I was surprised when I attempted to update manufacturer-bundled software and found that I couldn't because it wasn't installing through Google Play.

Is there a way to make my tablet understand that an app downloaded or upgraded through my OEM is just as safe as something downloaded through Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go to Settings -> Security and check the option: Unknown Sources (or something like that). then your tablet would allow you to install apps from everywhere.

Comment: This option should obviously be turned back off when you're done.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Why? I don't see **any** reason to do that.

Comment: Isn't this a security hole, allowing anyone to install apps on my tablet?

Comment: @lacqui maybe it makes security problem, but when this is not checked, you are never able to install any app from other sources than Google play. And, I always turn this option ON without any problems, because anyway all apps require your permission to install, except when you have rooted your phone and some malicious app installs another app silently!

Comment: Because there's no reason that the default option should be to allow all packages from anywhere. If you need to install exotic packages, it's better to disable the protection then, instead of leaving it always off. It's like asking "why should I have the safety on when using guns, I'm not an idiot". Why not use it when it's there. You have no way of knowing what situations your tablet will be put in (other people using it etc).

Comment: @bigbadonk420 If other people can install an app than they can also just enable unknown sources. Please stop with the metaphors - safety on guns is a totally different thing.

Comment: @bigbadonk420 ALso if you're replying to someone please "at" mention them so they will be notified.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik: one possible scenario is if a malicious app tried to trick you into click through the install button, for instance, it might be a game that asks you to quickly and repeatedly tap on the area where the install button usually is, with the right timing some people might accidentally click through the installation prompt without realizing it until it's too late. Gun safety exists for similar reason, anyone with little knowledge of guns can disable them, it's there to prevent pressing the trigger by accident, not to prevent the shooting itself.